# Getting ConstraintRaw Error

Tags: anchor, program

I'm integrating smart contract in next js. and getting this error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: custom program error: 0x7d3
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.browser.esm.js:7336:13)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.browser.esm.js:7302:20)
    at async claimSpot (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./app/[hostee]/events/[event]/page.tsx:72:21)
    at async claim (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./app/[hostee]/events/[event]/page.tsx:87:9
```

here's the code for it
https://gist.github.com/simplysabir/9b81bc573537b31ebada921b55a17b9f

and here's the sc part of it
https://gist.github.com/simplysabir/0914bcc3223ca92d3106f49a3a7d494c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check this constraint : constraint = token_mint.key() == event_account.token,

check if the event_account.token value is the same as the mint address you're using

Comment: yeah it's resolved. token address in event account was different.

Comment: nice ! so please could you accept my answer? thx !